# No reubicar DIV al IMPRIMIR

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, css3

Tengo un problema al cual no le puedo encontrar una explicación. Mi página está, a mi criterio, debidamente dividida en  que ocupan el 100% de la página y otros que ocupan el % necesario para que uno o más elementos entren en el div de 100%. En éste caso me sucede lo siguiente, hay un DIV especifico que al enviar a IMPRIMIR se reubica debajo de otro, generando una desproporción en la página. Dejo imagen que va a explicar mejor

(Antes de la impresión)

Las posiciones son las esperadas, el único detalle es que al DISMINUIR el font-size, llego a la misma conclusión que la foto donde esta mal el DIV, o sea, al disminuir el font-size, el DIV "conos" se pasa debajo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(En la impresión)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.page {
  position: relative;
  height: 1490px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 25cm;
  margin: 10px auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 30px 50px;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
}

.subsection.contenedores {
  width: 25%;
}

.subsection.conos {
  width: 74%;
}

.section-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.subsection {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="section contenedores">
  <div class="subsection contenedores">
    <div class="section-title">
      Contenedores
    </div>
    <div class="contenedores-chart">
      <table class="contenedores-table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Decanter</td>
            <td>
              <div class="decanter value">36</div>
              <div class="progress-bar-contenedores" style="width: 36%;"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Secadoras</td>
            <td>
              <div class="secadoras value">17</div>
              <div class="progress-bar-contenedores" style="width: 17%;"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zarandas</td>
            <td>
              <div class="zarandas value">6</div>
              <div class="progress-bar-contenedores" style="width: 6%;"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="subsection conos">
    <div class="section-title">
      Conos
    </div>
    <table class="section-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>QL</th>
          <th>QS</th>
          <th>QP</th>
          <th>R</th>
          <th>Kg sol Hs</th>
          <th>Lts Lodo Hs</th>
          <th>Lts Solidos Hs</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="desander">
          <td>Desander</td>
          <td class="ql"></td>
          <td class="qs"></td>
          <td class="qp"></td>
          <td class="r"></td>
          <td class="kg-sol-hs">-</td>
          <td class="lts-lodo-hs">-</td>
          <td class="lts-solidos-hs"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="desilter">
          <td>Desilter</td>
          <td class="ql"></td>
          <td class="qs"></td>
          <td class="qp"></td>
          <td class="r"></td>
          <td class="kg-sol-hs">-</td>
          <td class="lts-lodo-hs">-</td>
          <td class="lts-solidos-hs"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes implementar flexbox a al padre de los dos las substituciones, seria

```
display: flex
flex-direction: row
```

eso haría que ambas cajas siempre quedaran horizontalmente y no deberían de darte problema, a menos que de alguna forma el elemento que se baja se este cambiando de lugar y no se quede en el elemento padre